# Error in Azure IoT Edge runtime - A module runtime error occurred

Tags: azure-iot-edge

[iotedge list command error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHjZp.png)
Hi,
On running the iotedge list command it is throwing - A module runtime error occurred. Is there something missed. It was working fine till yesterday.

Comment: Have you checked the [various logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-1.4#gather-debug-information-with-support-bundle-command) to see what's up? Should that fail, check the [security manager logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-1.4#check-the-status-of-the-iot-edge-security-manager-and-its-logs).

Comment: You need to add more details about the issue which you are facing. What changes you have made to the IoT Edge? Try restarting  the IoT Edge runtime on your device by running the iotedge restart command and see if that resolves the issue?